# Do something when a for loop ends

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a for loop in JavaScript, and I want some code to run when it ends. This works, but I'm wondering if there are any simpler solutions:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log('Line ' + i);

    if (i === 100) {
        alert('Loop ended!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log('Line ' + i);
}

alert('Loop ended!');
```

Comment: Curse you, beating me to an easy answer...  Have a grudgingly given upvote.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that `for()` loops aren't async like `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you do like this?

```
Array.from(Array(100), (_, i) => console.log('Line ' + (i + 1)));
alert('Loop ended!');
```

Comment: I downvoted the above 3 answers for the same reason before. Always look for the accepted answer before making a decision

Comment: This answer was posted **in the same time** as the other answers (in 2010), it is also different from the other answers, so this is **not a duplicate**... You can't look for accepted answer when there is **no accepted answer at the time you post**. This was posted **2 minutes** after the question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

unless I'm missing something, what's wrong with:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log('Line ' + i);
}

alert('Loop ended!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
   console.log('Line ' + i);
}

alert('');
```